# What value goes into the receiving end's checksum header using TCP in Wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, checksum

so I was wondering, what value goes into the checksum header on the receiving end?

For example, if I am sniffing http data, and I receive a packet, how is the value in the checksum header calculated? I am pretty sure I got how to calculate checksum but I don't understand why the value is as it is.

basically you get the sum of the binary string while splitting the string into groups of 1 byte and lines of 2 bytes, and then operate a 1 complement thingy on that sum, and that's your checksum. and to verify, the receiving end calculates the sum by himself, and adds the checksum to the sum, if everything is 1 then the packet was sent with no errors and 0 is the opposite. but if that's the case shouldn't I see an "ff ff" checksum value? why does it look like "34 ef" instead?

I apologize if this is a stupid question but I just couldn't find the answer as much as I tried looking. Thanks!

Comment: `adds the checksum to the sum` no, it just compares two values

Comment: @IłyaBursov from what I've seen most people say that it checks if the checksum + sum adds to all 1s, you can google it if you'd like. but even if it does compare the two values, what would the checksum value be? and why would they be different on each side?

Comment: receiver can either validate that checksum is correct (ie calculate checksum and compare with received) or because of the properties of how this checksum is calculated: checksum + checksum = all 1s, so it can perform checksum calculation and then multiple it by two (ie checksum+checksum), but my point was - received does NOT update checksum in packet, it only verifies it (ie compares with calculated by itself), this is why you see some value in packet, it could be different if bits where mangled during transmission

Comment: @IłyaBursov but why if I look at the same packet from both the sender's end and the receiving end they will have different checksums? they have the same data, they're quite literally the same packet. just from different sides. so what makes the value change? (I get that they don't physically change but it shows a different value in the wireshark section.)

Comment: it is impossible, checksum should be the same, if it is different - they are different packets